# How do I get the Facebook Server Time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook iframe app using Flash on the client and .net on the server. I am using fluorineFX to communicate between the two.

I need to get the exact facebook server time from my server. This is for authenticating the user on my server so I **don't** want to get the time from the client and then pass it to the server. This is the only interaction I need with Facebook from my server, all other interaction is handled by the client using the old rest API.

What is the best way to do this? I have read you can use FQL but seeing as its just the time I am looking for is there a way which does not involve getting an authToken on the server?

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 4):

You can call now() in a Facebook FQL query to get the current Facebook server time in a unix timestamp and then convert it from there however you need.

For example, here is a sample FQL query that would work without an auth token (fql statements require a where clause so I just grabbed a random fql table with a random where statement):

```
SELECT now() FROM link_stat WHERE url = '1.2'
```

The url for that query would be:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+now%28%29+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+%3D+%271.2%27&format=json

Facebook provides a [FQL testing tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) to help.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know this is an old response, but I've been using it for the past 5 months. Now that FQL is being transitioned out, is there a way to obtain the same information without FQL but via a URL that responds with a JSON payload?