# Accessing facebook server time without FQL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Following up on this question:
[How do I get the Facebook Server Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952954/how-do-i-get-the-facebook-server-time)

Is there a way to get the facebook server time WITHOUT using FQL? I know that they are deprecating FQL soon. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: According to the old FQL query, Facebook uses UTC time on their servers so shouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to get the server time via the Graph API. It's not really clear to me *why* you need the server time from Facebook's servers. Can you elaborate a bit?

And, FQL will be around until August 7th 2016. I guess that should be sufficient, or do you just have an v2.1 app?

Comment: I need it because the app I'm building / maintaining has an exploit where the user could cause minor inconveniences to other users by changing his phone time to a time that isn't approximately the real time (e.g, changing his time to dec 31, 2000).

Comment: Is there another time server you know of that has practically no downtime?

Comment: Why don't you use the server time of the server your application is running on?

Comment: My backend service provider doesn't provide a point to access their server time, unfortunately.